# I can't add video to a Keynote on iOS

Tags: ios, video, keynote

I have a movie/video on my iPad.  It is located in the video file (not the photo album).  When I go to Keynote presentation to add this particular video and click on media, all that comes up are photo albums so I can't seem to access this video in the video file and therefore can't add it to Keynote.  What to do?

Comment: What is the format of this video you want to include? The videos recorded on the phone are all in QuickTime format (.mov). The Video app can read a few other formats like MPEG4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but your video **must** be in one of the photo albums or your Camera Roll.

In Keynote, tap the Add Object icon at the top-right of the display in Keynote for iOS:

- Tap the Media tab in the selection screen that appears.
- Tap the photo album that contains your video.
- Tap the video thumbnail you want.
- Tap Choose.

The thumbnail for the video will be placed on the slide and will play when tapped on.